# Using more than one scale in the tikz document

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am going to use two different `tikzpicture` sections within my `document`... The interest is using two different `[scale=x]` options for each one.
When I consider the `[scale=x]` for just one of them, everything is fine. But as I add the `[scale=y]` to the latter, too, I have an error as below:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/place' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.27 \node[place]
(waiting) {};
```

And one could check the code, as below snippet:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]

\foreach \x in {1, ..., 10} 
    \shadedraw[] (\x * 36:10) circle (1.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale = 2.0, transform shape, place/.style={circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick, inner sep = 0pt,
     minimum size=12}, 
     transition/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, fill=black!20, thick, inner sep = 0pt,         minimum size=8}]

     \node[place]      (waiting)                             {}; 
     \node[place]      (critical)       [below=of waiting]   {}; 
     \node[place]      (semaphore)      [below=of critical]  {}; 
     \node[transition] (leave critical) [right=of critical]  {}; 
     \node[transition] (enter critical) [left=of critical]   {};                         

     \node[red, above]  at (semaphore.north) {$s \le 3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it ever possible to do something like this?!...

Thanks in advance...

.................................

Edit: with the applied advices, the above code works...

Comment: Of course it is. You made two (minor) mistakes though. First, you need to end the first tikzpicture, so there needs to be an `\end{tikzpicture}` before the second `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Second, all options need to go in between the same (square) brackets, so `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0][...` needs to be `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0, place/.style=...`

Comment: If you do want them nested, then change the inner `tikzpicture` to `scope`.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt: Thank you... Now I have the output... but amazingly, changing the value of second `scale` has no effect on the second figure!, i.e. `[scale=5.0]` and `[scale=50.0]` just generate same outputs!!! What's going on?!

Comment: @kmacinnis: As I need independent scaling handling for each one, `scope` does not fit the case, deservedly...

Comment: @Ordenador Nothing is positioned by the use of coordinates. So there is nothing to scale but the shapes themselves. To accomplish that you need to add `transform shape` to your options. So you should go with `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0,transform shape,place/.style=...`

Comment: @MaartenDhondt: I would deeply appreciate for your nice guiding...

Comment: @MaartenDhondt You would normally be asked to write an answer but the OP has essentially turned the question into your answer, so I'm not sure whether that makes sense or not. Do you want to answer the no-longer question? Or should this be closed?

Comment: @cfr The reason I didn't write an answer is because I don't think it would help anyone else. The main problem was basically forgetfulness/typo. And the second problem that arose (`transform shape`) is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/why-does-fit-not-scale-tikz (I didn't flag it as such, since this was not the main question). I think this question can be closed but if anyone thinks an answer would we helpful, I'll happily write one.